# Why is reduceLeft complaining about type mismatch?

Tags: scala

I am trying to find the length of the longest line in a collection of lines.

```
  val lines = Source.fromFile(args(0)).getLines() //a collection of strings
  val longestLine = lines.reduceLeft( (a,b) =>
      if(a.length > b.length) a.length else b.length )
```

But this causes the following error:

```
/home/jesvin/dev/scala/readfile.scala:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: String
      if(a.length > b.length) a.length else b.length )
                                ^
/home/jesvin/dev/scala/readfile.scala:11: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Int
 required: String
      if(a.length > b.length) a.length else b.length )
                                              ^
two errors found
```

I tried some explicit return statements and typecasting at certain locations, but it did not work.

Am I using `reduceLeft` wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Am I using `reduceLeft` wrong?

Yes, you wanna have the behavior of a `fold` and not of a `reduce`. A `reduce` produces a type identical to the type parameter of a collection - it is `fold` which can produce another type.

```
scala> Seq("a","b","cd").reduceLeft(_+_)
res24: String = abcd
```

Here, the type parameter of Seq is String - therefore `reduceLeft` also produces a String.

```
scala> Seq("a","b","cd").foldLeft(0)(_+_.length)
res25: Int = 4
```

In contrast `foldLeft` can produce another type - in this example an Int.

In your example `seq.max` is what you want. Try to implement it by yourself and then when you got it look at the sources to verify if your implementation is correct.

Hints: A `reduce` is a `fold` which is implemented something like this:

```
def reduce(f: (A, A) => A) =
  tail.fold(head)(f)
```

This is the reason why `reduce` throws an exception when it is called to an empty collection.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you are.  reduceLeft must return an object of a type compatible the the ones in the collection - in this case, a String.  See [Programming in Scala](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/next-steps-in-scala.html) for *exactly* your problem - right down to the same variable names.

You want:

```
val longestLine 
  = lines.reduceLeft( (a,b) => if(a.length > b.length) a else b ).length
```

Of course, this only works if the collection is non-empty.  For this reason, and others, foldLeft is often preferable, as shown by @Antoras.

Comment: I _was_ writing the program at the end of Chapter 3 without looking at the original to find gaps in my learning. Turns out, I didnt know enough about reduce and fold operations in this case.